# Why are viewDidLayoutSubviews and viewWillLayoutSubviews called two times?

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: -property
//    lazy var testBtn: UIButton! = {
//        var btn: UIButton = UIButton()
//        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
//        print("testBtn lazy")
//        return btn
//    }()

    // MARK: -life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       print("View has loaded")
        // set the superView backgroudColor
//        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        // add testBtn to the superView
//        self.view.addSubview(self.testBtn)
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
       print("View will appear")
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
       print("View has appeared")
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
       print("View will disappear")
    }
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
       print("View has desappeared")
    }
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
       print("SubViews will layout")
        // layout subViews
//        'CGRectMake' is unavailable in Swift
//        self.testBtn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)
//        self.testBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100) // CGFloat, Double, Int
    }
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
       print("SubViews has layouted")
//        let testBtn_Width = self.testBtn.frame.width
//       print("testBtn's width is \(testBtn_Width)")
    }

}
```

The result:

> View has loaded
>   View will appear
>   SubViews will layout
>   SubViews has layouted
>   SubViews will layout
>   SubViews has layouted
>   View has appeared

As you see, I have created a new project and type some simple code.
I didn't change the size of the viewController's view.
Why are "SubViews has layouted" and "SubViews will layout" console two times?

Why are viewDidLayoutSubviews and viewWillLayoutSubviews called two times?

Comment: When Any view is resized these methods called. For just launch view it is posible that you design for iphone 8 in your xib/storyboard and run on different size device like iphone 8 plus or ipad.

Comment: @Shreyank I have set the "Main.storyboard"view as iPhone X and run the iPhone x simulator. The result shows too.

Comment: FWIW I've always just accepted this, understanding that there's no "guarantee" that it will be called once - instead, if you *must* have your code executed once in those two overrides, code with a flag.

Answer (score 0):

Because whenever `setNeedsLayout` or `setNeedsDisplayInRect` is being called internally, `LayoutSubviews` is also being called (once per run loop) on any given view. This applies for example if the view has been added, scrolled, resized, reused etc.